# Recommended way to store a string in this case?

Tags: mysql

I am storing strings and 99.5+% are less than 255 characters, so I store them in a VARCHAR(255).

The thing is, some of them can be 4kb or so. What's the best way to store those?

- Option #1: store them in another table with a pointer to the main.

  - Option #1.0: add an `INT` column with `DEFAULT NULL` and the pointer will be stored there
  - Option #1.1: the pointer will be stored in the `VARCHAR(255)` column, e.g `'AAAAAAAAAAA[NUMBER]AAAAAAAAAAAA'`
- Option #2: increase the size of `VARCHAR` from 255 to 32767

What's the best of the above, `Option #1.0`, `Option #1.1` or `Option #2`, performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the size of your field to fit the max size of your string. A VARCHAR will not use the space unless needed.

> VARCHAR values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte length prefix plus
>   data. The length prefix indicates the number of bytes in the value. A
>   column uses one length byte if values require no more than 255 bytes,
>   two length bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: No as long as long as your strings are under 32767, and it's a significantly better approach than #1 or #1.1. Think of how that would complicate your queries.

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL Definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) says that VARCHAR(N) will take up to `L + 1 bytes if column values require 0 – 255 bytes, L + 2 bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes` where L is the length in bytes of the stored string.

So I guess that option #2 is quite okay, because the small strings will still take less space than 32767 bytes.

**EDIT:**

Also imagine the countless problems options 1.0 and 1.1 would raise when you actually want to query a string without knowing whether it exceeds the length or not.

Answer (score 1):

`Option #2` is clearly best. It just adds 1 byte to the size of each value, and doesn't require any complicated joins to merge in the fields from the second table.